# Consecutive dropdown filtering missing default select value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

**Note:** The code snippet has been corrected and works.

In a MySQL table, I have the following columns (and respective values):

- Category (Fruit, Vegetable)
- Type (Apple, Orange, Pumpkin, Potato)
- Subtype (Red Delicious, Granny Smith, Fuji, Valencia, Navel, Kent, Butternut, Desiree, Carlingford)

Below is the code for the dropdowns and the JavaScript functions which change the options of the next dropdown based off the selection of values in the previous dropdown:

```js
var typeOptions = {};
typeOptions['Fruit'] = [
  'Apple',
  'Orange'
];
typeOptions['Vegetable'] = [
  'Potato',
  'Pumpkin'
];
typeOptions['Select a category'] = [];

function changeCategory() {
  var categoryChoice = document.getElementById('category');
  var typeChoice = document.getElementById('type');
  var selectedCategoryChoice = categoryChoice.options[categoryChoice.selectedIndex].value;
  while (typeChoice.options.length) {
    typeChoice.remove(0);
  }
  var typesAvailable = typeOptions[selectedCategoryChoice];
  if (typesAvailable) {
    selectType = document.createElement('option');
    selectType.text = 'Select a type';
    typeChoice.add(selectType);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < typesAvailable.length; i++) {
      var type = new Option(typesAvailable[i], typesAvailable[i]);
      typeChoice.options.add(type);
    }
  }
  var subtypeChoice = document.getElementById('subtype');
  if (selectedCategoryChoice == 'Select a category') {
    while (subtypeChoice.options.length) {
      subtypeChoice.remove(0);
    }
    selectSubtype = document.createElement('option');
    selectSubtype.text = 'Select a subtype';
    subtypeChoice.add(selectSubtype);
  }
};

var subtypeOptions = {};
subtypeOptions['Apple'] = [
  'Fuji',
  'Granny Smith',
  'Red Delicious'
];
subtypeOptions['Orange'] = [
  'Navel',
  'Valencia'
];
subtypeOptions['Potato'] = [
  'Carlingford',
  'Desiree'
];
subtypeOptions['Pumpkin'] = [
  'Butternut',
  'Kent'
];

function changeType() {
  var typeChoice = document.getElementById('type');
  var subtypeChoice = document.getElementById('subtype');
  var selectedTypeChoice = typeChoice.options[typeChoice.selectedIndex].value;
  while (subtypeChoice.options.length) {
    subtypeChoice.remove(0);
  }
  if (selectedTypeChoice == 'Select a type') {
    while (subtypeChoice.options.length) {
      subtypeChoice.remove(0);
    }
    selectSubtype = document.createElement('option');
    selectSubtype.text = 'Select a subtype';
    subtypeChoice.add(selectSubtype);
  }
  var subtypesAvailable = subtypeOptions[selectedTypeChoice];
  if (subtypesAvailable) {
    selectSubtype = document.createElement('option');
    selectSubtype.text = 'Select a subtype';
    subtypeChoice.add(selectSubtype);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < subtypesAvailable.length; i++) {
      var subtype = new Option(subtypesAvailable[i], subtypesAvailable[i]);
      subtypeChoice.options.add(subtype);
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <label for="category" id="categoryLabel" style="text-align: left">Category</label>
  <select name="category" id="category" onchange="changeCategory()" class="form-control">
    <option value="Select a category" selected>Select a category</option>
    <option value="Fruit">Fruit</option>
    <option value="Vegetable">Vegetable</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <label for="type" id="typeLabel" style="text-align: left">Type</label>
  <select name="type" id="type" onchange="changeType()" class="form-control">
    <option value="Select a type" selected>Select a type</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
  <label for="subtype" id="subtypeLabel" style="text-align: left">Subtype</label>
  <select name="subtype" id="subtype" class="form-control">
    <option value="Select a subtype" selected>Select a subtype</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The issue I have is that as soon as I select a value of the first dropdown, the "Select a type" section of the second dropdown and "Select a subtype" section of the third dropdown instantly disappear. When I select fruit for example in the first dropdown, the second dropdown defaults to Apple, yet the third dropdown does not show the Apple subtypes, and I have to switch to Orange, then back to Apple to show this.

Also, if I reset the first dropdown back to "Select a category", the second dropdown resets to blank and does not show "Select a type", while the third dropdown does not reset at all.

**Update:**

If I remove the following code:

```
while (typeChoice.options.length) {
  typeChoice.remove(0);
}
```

I can keep the default "Select a x" value, but it means that cumulative filtering no longer works properly (Selecting Orange for example after selecting Apple will just add Orange subtypes to the subtype dropdown without removing the Apple subtypes).

**Update 2:**

I attempted to add in a "Reset" button as per [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RSk9q/) to be able to reset all dropdowns, but it only resets the first one.

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('select').each(function() { this.selectedIndex = 0 });">Reset</a>
```

**Update 3:**

Got it working. Firstly an addition to the options for the second dropdown based off the first dropdown:

```
typeOptions['Select a category'] = [];
```

in combination with this just before the FOR loop that adds the new options of the second dropdown but after the WHILE loop that removes all old options of the second dropdown:

```
selectType = document.createElement('option');
selectType.text = 'Select a type';
typeChoice.add(selectType);
```

This ensures that when selecting a value in the first dropdown, the default value of 'Select a type' but in the second dropdown is retained, stays at the top of the dropdown and is still selected before the other options are added. When resetting the first dropdown to 'Select a category', the second dropdown will lose its remaining options then re-add the default value.

This is then added:

```
if (selectedCategoryChoice == 'Select a category') {
  while (subtypeChoice.options.length) {
    subtypeChoice.remove(0);
  }
  selectSubtype = document.createElement('option');
  selectSubtype.text = 'Select a subtype';
  subtypeChoice.add(selectSubtype);
}
```

This code checks the selected category choice, and if it is the default value as selected by the user, it resets the subtype.

This is similarly applied to the third dropdown when the second dropdown is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. Firstly an addition to the options for the second dropdown based off the first dropdown:

```
typeOptions['Select a category'] = [];
```

in combination with this just before the FOR loop that adds the new options of the second dropdown but after the WHILE loop that removes all old options of the second dropdown:

```
selectType = document.createElement('option');
selectType.text = 'Select a type';
typeChoice.add(selectType);
```

This ensures that when selecting a value in the first dropdown, the default value of 'Select a type' but in the second dropdown is retained, stays at the top of the dropdown and is still selected before the other options are added. When resetting the first dropdown to 'Select a category', the second dropdown will lose its remaining options then re-add the default value.

This is then added:

```
if (selectedCategoryChoice == 'Select a category') {
  while (subtypeChoice.options.length) {
    subtypeChoice.remove(0);
  }
  selectSubtype = document.createElement('option');
  selectSubtype.text = 'Select a subtype';
  subtypeChoice.add(selectSubtype);
}
```

This code checks the selected category choice, and if it is the default value as selected by the user, it resets the subtype.

This is similarly applied to the third dropdown when the second dropdown is changed.